# 'Baptist' Tag Synonyms

Tags: discussion, tag-synonyms

**I propose making [reformed-baptist](https://christianity.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/reformed-baptist) and [southern-baptist](https://christianity.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/southern-baptist) synonyms of [baptist](https://christianity.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/baptist).**

### Justification:

Other denominations do not have tags for each individual group under the main heading (e.g. all Lutherans, whether ELCA, WELS, NALC, LCMC, LCMS, etc. are all under [lutheranism](https://christianity.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/lutheranism)). Also, each of these proposed synonyms have only had *one* question for each in the past 12 months. Making them synonyms of baptist will make them easier to find. I would make the proposals myself but it won't let me as I don't have rep in these tags.

Comment: Hm. This is rather a mess. Even answers to you other tag questions are laking any over-arching consistency.

Answer (score 2):

No way! These need to remain separate tags.

Comment: I am afraid that merging them together would obscure their differences. I once met a person in real life who grew up Baptist, but not *Southern Baptist*. She treated it as if *Southern Baptist* was a dirty word. I think Southern Baptist is primarily Arminian in theology.

Comment: @Anonymous along that same line of thinking, do you propose having separate tags for all Lutherans and other denominations? Do we really want tags for every organization?

Comment: I think tags should lean more towards theological tradition than denomination or conservative/liberal. Arminianism and Calvinism are distinct theological traditions.

Comment: Your vote is dissonant with what you just said.

Comment: I did? I said the two Baptist denominations to stay separate tags. It complemented with my vote. I voted up this post, assuming that it concurs with what I said.

Comment: reformed-baptist should stay. southern-baptist would be most useful for historical questions I think, and there aren't likely to be many. And I think the SBC is slowly becoming less arminian, if it already isn't predominantly reformed.

Comment: @Anonymous Southern Baptist is a *denomination*. I don't mind how it works out (hence I answered both ways), just trying to create some order to all this. The impetus was [a query I'm working on](http://data.stackexchange.com/christianity/query/203428/quantity-of-questions-tagged-with-specific-christian-branches-of-faith) ;)

Comment: [updated query link](http://data.stackexchange.com/christianity/query/203428/quantity-of-questions-tagged-with-specific-christian-branches-of-faith)

Answer (score 2):

As large and with as clearly defined different Baptist groups are I think I could make a good case for them being broken out. That being said with one question each I think the lone tags can simply be removed and some other useful taxonomy employed. I do not see the need for a synonym at this time.

Comment: PS I don't mind what happens with these tags, I'm just trying to create some order/logic to it as it seems denomination-specific tags are not consistent across the board. Of course [there is a work-in-progress query](http://data.stackexchange.com/christianity/query/203428/quantity-of-questions-tagged-with-specific-christian-branches-of-faith) underlying some of this as well ;)

Comment: [updated query link](http://data.stackexchange.com/christianity/query/203428/quantity-of-questions-tagged-with-specific-christian-branches-of-faith)

Answer (score -3):

Great idea! We should definitely make [reformed-baptist](https://christianity.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/reformed-baptist) and [southern-baptist](https://christianity.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/southern-baptist) synonyms of [baptist](https://christianity.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/baptist).